# Get UTC date of last commit

Tags: bash, svn, datetime, timezone, commit

I'm trying to put together a bash/sh script that gets the UTC time of the last commit from a svn repo (the other VCSs are easy)
I understand that i can just do `svn propget --revprop -rHEAD svn:date` and get it rather easily, but there is no guarantee that the svn checkout will be online, so I'd prefer an offline version, if possible.

Maybe something to do with getting the UTC time from `svn info`? (by screwing with the timezones)

Summary: How can i get the UTC time of a svn commit, while not having access to the server?

Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: perhaps a little unclear, added a summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm silly. As soon as i actually realised i just need to convert one timezone to another, it was obvious:

```
date -u +[format] -d $(svn info | <some grepping and cutting here>)
```

In my case, this is:

```
date -u +"%Y%m%d-%H%M" -d "$(svn info | grep 'Date' | cut -d' ' -f4-6)"
```

Of course, my solution probably isn't optimal, and if someone knows a better way, that'd be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `svn log -r COMMITTED` and extract date info from it. This is valid for offline copies.

```
svn log -r COMMITTED | sed -nE 's/^r.*\| ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} \S+ \S+).*/\1/p' | xargs -i --  date -ud '{}' '+%s'
```

The `-u` option makes `date` show UTC time instead.

Actually we don't need to use `xargs`:

```
date -ud "$(exec svn log -r COMMITTED | sed -nE 's/^r.*\| ([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} \S+ \S+).*/\1/p')" '+%s'
```

UPDATE: I got the wrong command. The command above won't work offline. Here's the right one:

```
date -ud "$(svn info | sed -nE 's/^Last Changed Date: (\S+ \S+ \S+).*/\1/p')" '+%s'
```

Comment: Nice! You've used sed instead of my grep/cut combo. Would there be any significant difference?

Comment: @LordAro Nothing really just that.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the xml output of "svn info" has a zulu timestamp:

```
$ svn info --xml | grep date

<date>2015-04-30T15:38:49.371762Z</date>
```

So your bash command might be:

```
svn info --xml | grep -oP '(?<=<date>).*?(?=</date>)'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this post.  Ended up figuring out that svn uses env variable `TZ`, so for example:

```
TZ= svn log
```

will log dates in UTC

Comment: To clarify, this sets the `TZ` variable to an empty string for this command, then runs `svn log`.